# Unable to connect to postgres SQL with spring and hibrenate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have spring web application , that i am trying to connect with postgress.
Here is the db connection properties

```
datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampleDb
datasource.username=postgres
datasource.password=postgres
```

Here is the application context

```
<bean id="appDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${datasource.driver}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
         <value>${datasource.url}</value>
       </property>
       <property name="username">
         <value>${datasource.username}</value>
       </property>
       <property name="password">
         <value>${datasource.password}</value>
       </property>

    </bean>
```

When i starting application it get an error messege.

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Why would this happen?

I restored this database form another machine.I dont know what they written in that sql file. There is a code in that sql dump file.

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE workflow_type FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE workflow_type FROM postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE workflow_type TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,REFERENCES,UPDATE ON TABLE workflow_type TO user1;
```

Is this happend becouse of this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to connect with psql under command line before? its just to test if you pg_hba.conf was fine.

if you can't connect with psql. Open you pg_hba.conf file and if you are on a local computer replace md5 by trust to have something like :

```
 local   all         all                             trust
```

this permit everybody to connect to you postgres server.
retry connection with psql command line.

If its work, retry to launch your server to see if spring can now connect to the db fine.

Comment: save your pg_hba.conf, and change all md5 by trust, restart postgres is needed and try again. And did you try to connect via command line? does it works?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Postgres up and running on localhost:5432?  Are you able to connect to the DB via command line (e.g. `psql <dbname> -h localhost -U <username> -W`)?